# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi servidor local no sólo pueda ejecutarlo en el dispositivo que es el host usando GO?

Tags: localhost, go

Estoy usando GO para las conexiones en vez de PHP/XAMPP, por eso decidí hacerlo a través de este medio. Yo quisiera ver mi servidor desde mi teléfono y la verdad no sé si eso sea posible. De antemano les agradecería por su ayuda.

[image: Datos de mi servidor local]

Este es mi código actualmente:

```
import (
  "flag"
  "net/http"
  "fmt"
)

/*
Declare variables that show things
about your server.
*/
var staticDirectory string
var serverHost string
var serverPort int

func main()  {

  //
  flag.StringVar(&staticDirectory, "dir", "./", "Static assets directory")
  flag.StringVar(&serverHost, "host", "0.0.0.0", "Default server host")
  flag.IntVar(&serverPort, "port", 3000, "Server port")

  //execute help server
  flag.Parse()

  //read html file
  mux := http.NewServeMux()
  mux.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(staticDirectory)))
  http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", serverHost, serverPort), mux)
}
```

Comment: Lo que podrias hacer es si puedes conectar tu telefono a la red donde esta tu computadora, abrir el puerto de tu go server desde las opciones de windows https://www.solvetic.com/tutoriales/article/2657-como-abrir-o-cerrar-un-puerto-con-el-firewall-en-windows-10/
luego checas la ip de tu computadora en la red local y desde tu telefono accedes a la IP_DE_TU_PC:PUERTO_DE_TU_SERVER de otra maneras, puedes usar el nrok para hacer un tunel a tu server
https://www.jasoft.org/Blog/post/tutorial-ngrok-como-publicar-en-internet-cualquier-pagina-o-aplicacion-web-que-tengas-en-tu-equipo-local.aspx Espero

Comment: La manera más útil para exponer un puerto de un servicio local (sin pelearte con el cortafuegos de la máquina local) es usar un servicio como [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). Esto te creará una URL que puedes acceder desde internet y la enruta a tu servicio local al puerto indicado. Además te permite ver las conexiones realizadas y su contenido con lo que resulta muy útil para depurar.
Otra utilidad de este estilo y open source es [localtunnel](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel)